# About text and navigation hierarchy on mobile

Tags: mobile, navigation, ux-field

I'm making a mobile page that is heavy on content and I was wondering what people's thoughts are on hierarchy in regard to an "about" text and the main page navigation.

A quick outline of the product (as much as possible anyway), this mobile page  will act as an about area. The main "About" text will be in the same place and available on both pages, and is just a short synopsis, the bulk of the deep info will be found down the page on "about".

My question is, should the navigation be above the text or is it ok to see it after the text? I know the latter isn't the norm but could it be deemed as acceptable on this example?

I hope that makes some sense, I look forward to hearing what people think.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference between "more" and "about", really? Sounds to me like they're functionally the same; they take you to a more expanded text. Personally, I'd probably remove the about button and put the reviews button [82 reviews ★★☆] up top next to the product logo.

Hm, in fact, I might just remove the 'more' button entirely. Is there a particular reason why you won't put the whole product description on the page?

Also, maybe it's a good idea to collate the hero image and video?

Anyway here's a mockup:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Ive changed the title of the nav buttons as there may be some issues regarding what Im showing. Its more a question of the place holder text being above or below the nav and being in the same position on both pages, whilst the information under changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with V1, simply because majority of website and navigation standards have been always anchored somewhere on the top of the page. It is always comforting to know you can just go back to top and find your way around....unless of course your content is heavy on the scroll and have no "back to top" button then it might be a good idea to have it on the bottom as well. I like what Theo proposed on the reviews, but its more of a rating, and to read reviews it would still have to be a link/button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to go with V1 or V2 only and assuming you are only asking about nav placement.

**I would go with V2**

A visitor most likely is interested in a product. Showing a hero, product name and marketing description will give a visitor a quick overview. "About" and "Reviews" are secondary.

**Even better UX**

If you are open to a more usable layout, I would suggest doing what PixelSnader suggested. Bring and place review rank below the hero image and add "About" CTA much lower on the page, assuming that "More ..." and "About" CTA's do different things.